# Find all values of $(2-2i)^i$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all values of $(2-2i)^i$

Attempt:
$$\begin{align*}(2-2i)^i&=e^{i\ln(2-2i)}\\
&=e^{i[\ln\sqrt{8}-i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k)]}\\
&=e^{i\ln\sqrt{8}}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k}\\
&=[\cos(\ln\sqrt{8})+i\sin(\ln\sqrt{8})]e^{\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k}
\end{align*}$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Is this all? or am I missing something?

Comment: I have got $$e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\cos(\frac{3\ln(2)}{2})+i\sin(\frac{3\ln(2)}{2})\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : That's only one value, there are infinitely many others (OP asks for *all* values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right. I suppose you might quibble over how to write $\ln\sqrt{8}$ (for example, it could be written $\frac32\ln 2$), but your method is correct.